# i want to know how Scanner code works in Java

Tags: java

it's my first time to ask in this community
first, please excuse my poor english in advance

i want to know how Scanner code works

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);        ------Call it "A" for convenience
System.out.print("first number:");

String strNum1 = scanner.nextLine();



System.out.print("second number:");                  -----Call it "B" for convenience

String strNum2=scanner.nextLine();



int num1 = integer.parseInt(strNum1);              ---- Call it "C" for convenience

int num2 = integer.parseInt(strNum2);



int result = num1 + num2;

System.out.println("Add result: " + result);
```

Question is about Process of

in the moment i input some number in `Console` after [code above] is implemented
how [code above] interact(?) with result in Console

For example , when i input code above, run it 
and i input some number in console

(1)  input 1  -> output in console -  "first number:1"

(2)  input 3  -> output in console -  "first number:1"  "Second number:3" "Result: 4"

i can see this

So,

does it mean, when the process up to (1) is input, Progress to "A" shows up?

if it's right,  that 'scanner.nextLine()' is input at first as "1" Is the process of (1)

But, although the variable 'strNum1' is not run by 'System.out.println()'
Why can i see this number "1" ??

And,
Why doesn't `System.out.print("first number")` appears at first,
unless i input some number like "1"
in connection with `String strNum1 = scanner.nextLine();`

Comment: You want to know why it's waiting before it continues, right?

Comment: `System.out.print("first number:");` doesn't appear because Console is waiting for input first. Code is being executed line by line, so if you put input (System.in) first, it will wait for input before continuing.

Comment: @Matrix4290 Exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to get a string from the user and after that parse it to int If you only want to connect two numbers , you can get a int from the user and use with `scanner.nextInt()` , This will save you code lines and efficiency.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  


int num1 = scanner.nextInt();

int num2 = scanner.nextInt();


int result = num1 + num2;

System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = "+ result);
```

When you working with string you need to use with `scanner.nextLine();` or if you work with a number that start with `0`(like maybe id) string is the right thing , because int cant be start with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's dig in it (yes, line by line).

1. You create the `Scanner` object which takes as input the common input stream provided by the `System.in`, in that case the console itself.
2. Then, you are calling System.out.**print** which is different from System.out.**println**
3. System.out.print will simply append to the current state of the console the value you provided
4. Scanner gets call in using the `nextLine()` methods, **this block the process until some input is inserted inside the console terminal**, this is how usually the console works, you input something, press enter and it gets executed. More or less, it's the same in that case, scanner wait until you provide a line separator (press enter).
5. The exact same stuff happens for the scanner B
6. The numbers gets parsed and in the end their output is appended to the terminal with `System.out.println()`

**Let's summarise:**
Scanner block the thread until it receives an input, then it gets parsed and the normal flow of the routine goes on. A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, in that case of `nextLine()` the delimiter pattern is the `System.lineSeparator();`